# Compilation error when creating pl/sql stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, compilation, cursor

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that used **REF CURSOR**. I am using this [website](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/2222781/Returning-Rows-Through-a-Table-Function-in-Oracle.htm#fig1) to find some examples. First I created types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ROW_TYPE IS OBJECT (
"COL1" CHAR(3 BYTE), 
"COL2" NUMBER(4,0)
)

CREATE TYPE ROW_TYPE_TABLE AS TABLE OF ROW_TYPE;
```

Then created packages:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE package AS 
FUNCTION get_by_id(p_id CHAR) RETURN ROW_TYPE_TABLE PIPELINED;
END package;
```

But when creating package body using the following  command I get the following message **PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR"**

I have checked on [Oracle official website](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/openfor_statement.htm) how to use the **open-for** statement but can't find my mistake.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package AS
FUNCTION get_by_id(p_idCHAR) RETURN SERV_TYPE_TABLE PIPELINED IS
    OUT_REC SERV_TYPE_TABLE := SERV_TYPE_TABLE(null,null);
    servCursor sys_refcursor;
    OPEN servCursor FOR 'SELECT * FROM SERV WHERE COL1= :1' USING p_id;

    LOOP 
        FETCH servCursor INTO   OUT_REC.COL1,   OUT_REC.COL;
        EXIT WHEN servCursor%NOTFOUND;
        PIPE ROW(OUT_REC);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE servCursor;
    RETURN;
END get_by_id;
END package ;
```

Do you see any problem in the code submitted?

Regards.

Comment: add `BEGIN` after `servCursor sys_refcursor;` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PL/SQL functions have the structure:

```
FUNCTION <function name>(parameter1 <type>, ...) RETURN <return type> IS
    <variable declarations>
BEGIN
    <function body (code)>
END <function name>;
```

You forgot the `BEGIN`.